# Python Popen using PIPE issue

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to replicate this command using python and Popen:

```
echo "Acct-Session-Id = 'E4FD590583649358F3B712'" | /usr/local/freeradius/bin/radclient -r 1 1.1.1.1:3799 disconnect secret
```

When running this from the command line as it is above, I get the expected:

```
Sent Disconnect-Request Id 17 from 0.0.0.0:59887 to 1.1.1.1:3799 length 44
```

I want to achieve the same from a python script, so I coded it like this:

```
rp1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "Acct-Session-Id = 'E4FD590583649358F3B712'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
rp2 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/freeradius/bin/radclient",
                     "-r 1",
                     "1.1.1.1:3799",
                     "disconnect",
                     "secret"],
                     stdin = rp1.stdout,
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

rp1.stdout.close()

result = rp2.communicate()

print "RESULT: " + str(result)
```

But, I  must be doing this incorrectly as the "result" variable contains the radclient usage info, as if it is called incorrectly:

```
RESULT: ('', "Usage: radclient [options] server[:port] <command> [<secret>]\n  <command>....
```

Anybody any idea where my mistake lies?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a subprocess for the first command? it's just an `echo`

Comment: `"-r 1"` should be separate arguments: `"-r", "1"`

Comment: @Rawing, that is it! Thanks a million for that!

Comment: But you should really decommission that `echo` as a subprocess.  Just write the string into the input of the other subprocess with Python means.  This will make everything way simpler.

Comment: Thanks Alfe and Vinny - I will look into doing that

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen([ 'tr', 'x', 'u' ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, `p.stdin.write('mcxxi'); p.stdin.close()`, `p.stdout.read()` → `mcuui`  (But stay aware of the usual buffering problems which might occur.)

Comment: @Alfe: Those buffering problems are why you would replace the `write`, `close` and `read` with a single call to `communicate`, which eliminates the  buffering problems.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, `communicate()` should do fine in this case.  I only reluctantly use it because it does what it does exactly once (and waits sometimes arbitrarily long for any response), but in cases like these it is very likely sufficient.

Comment: @Alfe: Actually, as of Python 3.3, [`communicate` supports a `timeout` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) so you can bound the time spent waiting for a response. Yes, it only does a single input/output, so live back-and-forth communication isn't possible, but the only way to do that safely is to use threads or `select`/`selectors` module primitives (the same way `communicate` does) to manage sending and pulling data in a deadlock-free fashion. Much more complicated, but the only way to do it safely without `communicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides **@Rawing** catch of the args typo, you can make it much simpler with a single Popen process. Try this:

```
rp = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/freeradius/bin/radclient",
                     "-r",
                     "1",
                     "1.1.1.1:3799",
                     "disconnect",
                     "secret"],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

result = rp.communicate("Acct-Session-Id = 'E4FD590583649358F3B712'")
```

Using `communicate` to handle all the I/O prevents possible deadlocks that are possible when explicitly writing to `stdin` when you also need to read from `stdout`/`stderr`.

Comment: Much better solution: Don't pass `bufsize=0`, and instead of calling `write` or `close`, pass the string you're passing to `write` to `communicate` (which, as the name implies, "communicates", passing the argument to the process `stdin`, but safely, preventing deadlocks which your attempt at unbuffering the process can't prevent).

Comment: You're totally right. I forgot you can pass communicate args; thanks for pointing that

Comment: Yar. One additional note: If this is Py3, the input string should be `bytes`, not `str` (so prefix with `b`).

Comment: I have done that now and it works a charm - much simpler and neater solution. Thanks for that!